# Matchit with condition such as excluding

Tags: r, match

I am using the matchit package in R to match a data sample with treatment. The function is something like sales = price + location_zip. The prodcut has one other characteristics: category (ie., with numbers 1,2,3...). If I don't want to the matched control product in the same category (**excluding** matching within the **same category**), is there any good way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Your question will be closed unless you post a [MCVE] of you problem. Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to learn how to ask a good question that gets helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to exclude pairs in `MatchIt` package based on custom condition. However you can use `Matching` package and impose the exclusion restriction as below:

> Exclusion restriction are even more common. For example, if we want to
>   exclude the observation pair 4 and 20 and the pair 6 and 55 from being
>   matched, the restrict matrix would be:
>   restrict=rbind(c(4,20,-1),c(6,55,-1))